# Plot ellipses in a exponential curve

Tags: plotting, intersection

I am trying to produce a single plot, where the ellipses fits neatly within the given curve function, and with each intersecting the curve at exactly 4 points.

- The ellipses is  $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$, where $a=0.5, 0.6, 0.7, ...,
     2.0$, where $a>0$,$b>0$ and $πab=5$.  Hint: use **Table** to create all of them in one command.
- The curve $|y|=5/(2π|x|)$, drawn in black.  Be sure that the curve
  appears, and draw the single curve on top of the ellipses so that it
  is clearly visible.

What I tried to do was

```
Clear[x, y]
ellipse = x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1;
curve = Abs[y] == 5/(2*Pi*Abs[x]);
ell = Table[ellipse, {a, 0.5, 2.0, 0.5}, {b, 5/Pi*a}];
curvep = ContourPlot[Evaluate[curve], {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, 
   ContourStyle -> Black];
ellipsep = 
  ContourPlot[Evaluate[ell], {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, 
   ContourStyle -> Rainbow];
Show[ellipsep, curvep]
```

but for some reason, my ellipses are not fitting inside the curve function and rather it is outside.

[image]

Comment: `With[{ellipses = 
   Table[Circle[{0, 0}, {a, 5/(a \[Pi])}], {a, 0.5, 2.0, 0.1}]},
 ContourPlot[Abs[y] == 5/(2 Pi Abs[x]), {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, 
  Epilog -> {Opacity[.5], ellipses}, ContourStyle -> Thick]
 ]`

Comment: Can you use a different command without "With".

Comment: Why is the range for a {0.5,2.0,0.1}? where did 0.1 come from?

Comment: The requirements for ellipses are “where =0.5,0.6,0.7,...,2.0”, which tells us that the increment between 0.5 and 0.6, and between 0.6 and 0.7, etc. is **0.1**. If you use **0.5**, then =0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0 which is not what’s required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the equations of `ellipse`, replace `b` by `5/(Pi*a)` so just one parametric say `a`, then it is easy to create a table `ell` satisfy `Pi*a*b=5`

```
Clear["`*"];
Clear[x, y]
ellipse = x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1 /. b -> 5/(Pi*a);
curve = Abs[y] == 5/(2*Pi*Abs[x]);
ell = Table[ellipse, {a, 0.5, 2.0, 0.5}];
curvep = ContourPlot[Evaluate[curve], {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, 
   ContourStyle -> Black];
ellipsep = 
  ContourPlot[Evaluate[ell], {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}];
Show[ellipsep, curvep]
```

[image]